# сделать AVL-дерево деревом поиска по значениям и AVL-деревом по ключам

Tags: c, дерево, osdev

Пишу свой менеджер памяти для ОС. Возникла такая проблема: строю AVL-дерево по размеру свободных блоков, при этом для одинаковых размеров должно быть выполнено условие по значению(значение - адрес памяти), как в дереве поиска, т.е. если мы сбалансировали дерево, и у нас возникла ситуация, когда у какого-то поддерева у корня, у правого и левого потомка одинаковый ключ, то надо выполнить условие дерева поиска для данного поддерева по значениям, т.е. значение левого меньше, чем корня, корня меньше, чем правого, но из-за балансировки и поворотов данное условие может не выполнятся для каждого поддерева(повороты и балансировка по ключам, им плевать на значения).
Сам вопрос: как можно модифицировать что-либо в дереве, чтобы все условия выполнялись?

`void* avltree_get_from_idx(avltree_t* me, int idx)
{
    return me->nodes[idx].key;
}

void avltree_rotate_left(avltree_t* me, int idx)
{
    int p;

    p = __parent(idx);

    /* A Partial
    * Move Y out of the way so that X can take its spot */
    __shift_down(me, __child_l(p), __child_l(__child_l(p)));
    memcpy(&me->nodes[__child_l(p)], &me->nodes[p], sizeof(node_t));

    /* B */
    __shift_down(me, __child_l(idx), __child_r(__child_l(p)));
    me->nodes[__child_l(idx)].key = NULL;

    /* A Final
    * Move Y into X's old spot */
    __shift_up(me, idx, p);
}

static void __rebalance(avltree_t* me, int idx)
{

    while (1)
    {
        if (2 <= abs(
            __height(me, __child_l(idx)) -
            __height(me, __child_r(idx))))
        {
            /*  balance factor left node */
            int bf_r;

            bf_r = __height(me, __child_l(__child_r(idx))) -
                __height(me, __child_r(__child_r(idx)));

            if (bf_r == -1)
            {
                avltree_rotate_left(me, __child_r(idx));
            }
            else
            {
                avltree_rotate_left(me, __child_r(idx));
                avltree_rotate_right(me, __child_r(idx));
            }
        }

        if (0 == idx) break;
        idx = __parent(idx);
    }
}`

Comment: *как можно модифицировать что-либо в дереве, чтобы все условия выполнялись?* - это вопрос не про я зык С, а из теории алгоритмов. Теорию надо читать. Например: https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2/%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9B-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE

Comment: Что мешает иметь 2 независимых дерева? Одно по адресам (вы ведь собираетесь использовать его при возвращении блока для слияния соседей?), а другое по размерам (кстати, туда лучше вставлять один блок, который будет заголовком списка одинаковых (или лучше близких?) по размеру. Ну, все указатели (по 3 на дерево, ведь?) можно запихнуть прямо в сам блок (он же свободный, ни к чему другому не пригоден).

Comment: @avp можно иметь тогда дерево деревьев иметь, но ведь для дерева нужно выделение памяти, а для выделения памяти - дерево, по этому я зафигачил статический массив, но вложить дерево в дерево уже не получится статическим методом(получится, но расход памяти на пустые элементы огромный - что не есть хорошо), вот и думаю как сделать двойное дерево по ключам и значениям.

Comment: Сами по себе пустые блоки это и есть уже выделенная память. Указатели встраиваете в них и никакого дополнительного расхода памяти не нужно